# Why the UIImage is not released by ARC when I used UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext inside of a block

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, uiimage, automatic-ref-counting

I try to download an image from server by using the NSURLSessionDownloadTask(iOS 7 API), and inside of the completion block, I want to the original image to be resized and store locally. So I wrote the helper method to create the bitmap context and draw the image, then get the new image from UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(). The problem is the image is never released every time I do this. However, if I don't use the context and image drawing, things just work fine and no memory increasing issue. There is no CGImageCreate/Release function called, so really nothing to manually release here, and nothing fixed by adding @autoreleasepool here. Is there any way to fix this? I really want to modify the original image after downloading and before storing.

Here is some snippets for the issue:

```
[self fetchImageByDownloadTaskWithURL:url completion:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error) {

    UIImage *modifiedImage = [image resizedImageScaleAspectFitToSize:imageView.frame.size];

    // save to local disk
    // ...
}];

// This is the resize method in UIImage Category
- (UIImage *)resizedImageScaleAspectFitToSize:(CGSize)size
{
    CGSize imageSize = [self scaledSizeForAspectFitToSize:size];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, YES, 0.0);
    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height);
    [self drawInRect:imageRect]; // nothing will change if make it weakSelf
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

---

updates:

When I dig into with allocations instrument, I find out that the memory growth is related with "VM: CG raster data". In my storing method, I use the NSCache for a photo memory cache option before store it persistently, and the raster data eats a lot of memory if I use the memory cache. It seems like after the rendered image being cached, all drawing data is also alive in memory until I release all cached images. If I don't memory cache the image, then non of raster data that coming from my image category method will be alive in memory. I just can not figure out why the drawing data is not released after image is being cached? Shouldn't it being released after drawing?

new updates:

I still didn't figure out why raster data is not being released when image for drawing is alive, and there is no analyze warning about this for sure. So I guess I just have to not cache the huge image for drawing to fit the big size, and remove cached drawing images when I don't want to use them any more. If I call [UIImage imageNamed:] and make it drawing, it seems never being released with raster data together since the image is system cached. So I called [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:] instead.  Eventually the memory performs well. Other memory growth are something called non-object in allocations instrument which I have no idea currently. The memory warning simulation will release the system cached image created by [UIImage imageNamed:]. But for raster data, I will give some more tests on tomorrow and see.

Comment: ps: I am not sure that the unreleased image which causes the memory issue is the new rendered image or the original one. If you try the code or the idea yourself, probably encounter the same issue.

Comment: Try running an Analyze pass on your code.  If clang doesn't point out any ownership problems, perhaps you can ignore the memory usage.  It seems like UIImage or CoreGraphics is caching stuff on its own.  Perhaps simulate a low memory condition and see if the framework releases this memory.

Comment: Too mush informations, so I updated the post again.

Comment: The raster data will be released by system when encountered the low memory situation. Before that, it will remain alive when the drawing image is alive. That is the result from my testing.

Answer (score 0):

Try making your category method a class method instead.  Perhaps the leak is the original CGImage data which you are overwriting when you call `[self drawInRect:imageRect];`.

Comment: Thanks @Avi points it out. However, I didn't make any difference for changing it to class method. I discovered some progress and updated the post. Because it's too long to fit here, so I can't write as comment.